# Eclipse Neon 3 (4.6.3) is giving publishing error while deploying Node js onto IBM Bluemix

Tags: node.js, eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools, ibm-cloud-plugin

Whenever I am trying to publish the node.js application on Bluemix from Eclipse Neon 3 (4.6.3)` its giving me publish failure error.

> An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to IBM Bluemix...".
>   org.eclipse.cft.server.client.v2.internal.V2CFClientProvider.supports(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/cft/server/core/internal/client/CFInfo;)Z

Comment: When you vote down a question, please state why you are down voting it in these comments so that the newer members of the community can improve their questions!

Comment: Are you getting any other error messages? There's not much to go on here. Have you tried to publish it again?

Comment: yeah Bill, I tried to publish again but no luck again.

Comment: while adding the Bluemix server, I have used the option of "Use one time password to login(SSO)" because my Bluemix credentials were not working.

Comment: If your Bluemix credentials are not working, you can reset your IBMid here: https://www.ibm.com/account/us-en/forgot/forgot-password-start.html

Comment: Bill, I am an IBM employee and so whenever I try to login to Bluemix in browser, it always says that my email is already associated with W3ID and asks me to use my W3ID. With my W3ID I am able to login to Bluemix in browser but same W3ID credentials are not working when I provide them in creating Bluemix server in Eclipse.

Comment: As per Bluemix support team I should use the option 'Use one time password to login(SSO)' while creating the Bluemix server. So created the server with this option and pushed the application. Application is getting pushed to Bluemix correctly and I can see the app on Bluemix web UI but application is not able to start and getting same error "Publishing to IBM Bluemix..."

Comment: Weird thing is when I am starting the same app from Bluemix Web UI its getting started successfully.Once it started from Bluemix Web UI then I stopped the app from eclipse and tried to publish again and it got published successfully. So it seems I need to follow this workaround until problem of eclipse is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Santosh, I am able to reproduce the issue.

I can confirm this is a bug introduced in a recent version: when you attempt to publish a JavaScript application with an SSO Bluemix server from Eclipse Neon.3, you will encounter the exception listed above. The specific issue is a method signature mismatch between versions of Eclipse CFT.

We will work to fix this in our next release, however, to help you in the mean time, these are some workarounds:

- If you install Eclipse Tools for Bluemix onto the latest release of Eclipse -- Eclipse Oxygen -- you will no longer see this problem. This issue only occurs with Eclipse Neon.
- If you use an Eclipse Bluemix server configured without SSO, eg with a email/password, you will not encounter this issue.
- Another option is to deploy your application from the console, using the CF CLI. You would use the 'cf push' command in this scenario, from the directory of your application.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I have created the server exactly the same way. Only thing is in step 4 I have chose the option as "Use one time password to login(SSO)" because my bluemix credentials were giving error.